# How to fix the error: Resource android:style/Theme.AppCompat.light.noActionBar not found

Tags: android, gradle

I am in the middle of creating an app for my culminating project that is due in several days. I was creating a new activity but I initially named it something I didn't want to. I deleted the activity file and the errors occurred. The following errors are: 
resource android:style/Theme.AppCompat.light.noActionBar not found.
error: failed linking references. Error occurs during the Run Tasks part of the Build. I am on Android Version 3.1.1.

All instances of R don't work as well; with a message saying cannot resolve symbol 'R'. I've looked at several other solutions but unfortunately it doesn't check out with my problem.

I've tried clean / rebuild but unfortunately, that hasn't gone well.
I have also tried invalidating caches/restart, as well as a fresh reinstall.

Here is my build.gradle
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

```
android {

    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.henry.henryso"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    //appcompat
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'

    //Recycler View
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'

    //Toolbar design support
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
}
```

Comment: Is that an incorrect name? That's `Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar`.

Comment: @ShubhamPanchal I have corrected that in my styles.xml, but the same error still exists. It is a APPT2 error.